# Is there a way to generate java classes from MS-Dataset XSD files?

Tags: java, xsd, code-generation, dataset

Given a Dataset XSD file, is it possible to generate java classes, that don't make use of System.Data?
I've tried running a test using JAXB's XJC tool, but it doesn't produce anything terribly useful.

Update: I've tried XmlBeans also, following Fernando's suggestion, and it generates something similar to the XJC output - that is, class representations of the tables, but without any columns, constraints, or rows. I can add these things in a facade, but ideally they would be generated by whatever XSD compiler was used.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) instead of JAXB API. You can invoke it be means of command line command or just use an ANT script. I past the part of a build.xml file that invokes XMLBeans to compile XSD to a jar file.

```
<taskdef name="xmlbean" classname="org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean" classpathref="classpath"/>


<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!--  Crea y compila las clases del modelo                             -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<target name="build" description="--> crea las clases a partir del schema">
    <!-- Borra los fuentes del modelo -->
    <delete quiet="true" dir="${build.dir}/src" />

    <mkdir dir="${build.classes}"/>

    <!-- Construye fuentes asociadas y crea las clases -->
    <xmlbean srcgendir="${build.dir}/src" classpathref="classpath" classgendir="${build.classes}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.xsd"/>
        <fileset dir="${schemas.dir}" includes="**/*.*"/>
    </xmlbean>

    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" 
                destdir="${build.classes}" 
                encoding="Windows-1252" 
                debug="${debug}" 
                debuglevel="${debuglevel}" 
                deprecation="${deprecation}" 
                verbose="${verbose}" 
                optimize="${optimize}" 
                source="${source}" 
                target="${target}">
                <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: The XmlBeans scomp compiler (is this what you meant?) generates reasonable code from an MS-Dataset XSD, but it looses all information about columns, constraints, etc. I get a similar result from XJC.